# Determine if $g=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/3}e_n$ exists in Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

In a Hilbert space I have an orthogonal basis $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$

I want to find out if an element $g \in \mathcal{H}$ is defined using:

$g=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/3}e_n$

I think this is only possible if the sum converges. However I don't know how to handle the converge. For a p-series it would not converge because we require $p>1$. But here we are also multiplying with $e_n$ so I am not sure how this affects the sum because each term is a separate coordinate in g

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Does $\sum_n n^{-2/3}$ converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a sequence of real numbers $\left(a_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, can we define 
$$
v=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_ne_n
$$
by $v=\lim_{N\to +\infty}v_N$ where $v_N:=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_ne_n$?

Since a Hilbert space is complete, this is doable if and only if the sequence $\left(v_N\right)_{N\geqslant 1}$ is Cauchy for the norm induced by the inner product. Since for fixed $M$ and $N$, $\lVert v_{N+M}-v_N\rVert^2=\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+M}a_n^2$, the necessary and sufficient condition is the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n^2$.

This is in particular not satisfied for $a_n=n^{-1/3}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\left\lVert\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{-1/3}e_n\right\rVert^2=\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{-2/3}$.

Comment: How do you get this result? I tried $$\bigg|\bigg| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}e_n \bigg|\bigg|^2= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg| \langle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/3}}e_n, e_n \rangle  \bigg|^2$$ but it doesn't get me there

Comment: If $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal and both of them have norm $1$, and if $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$, then\begin{align}\lVert\alpha v+\beta w\rVert^2&=\langle\alpha v+\beta w,\alpha v+\beta w\rangle\\&=\alpha^2\langle v,v\rangle+\alpha\beta\langle v,w\rangle+\alpha\beta\langle w,v\rangle+\beta^2\langle w,w\rangle\\&=\alpha^2+\beta^2.\end{align}

Comment: Oh, I just realized that this is Parseval's identity...! Thanks